# Debugging 'Object Required line 1' Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Take for example;

IE7 / IE7 Mode- IE8 & IE9 @ [http://psc.gov/](http://psc.gov)

IE8/IE7 are totally unhelpful: 'Object required line 1'

In IE9- IE7 mode, I get a different, slightly more frustratingly-almost-helpful message:

"Unable to get the value of the property 'offsetHeight': object is null or undefined"
(again at line 1 char 1)

grep-ing for 'offsetHeight' yields around 470 lines of code in various files. Obviously, digging through hundreds of files is not the ideal solution...

How does one go about debugging this? I've tried using Visual Studio, but I cannot get IE to pass the debugging session to Visual Studio while in IE7 mode.

So the question twofold;

1) How do I debug these sorts of errors?

2) How do I pass a debugging session while in IE7 mode to Virtual Studio?

Any other helpful nuggets you'd like to bestow are appreciated (tools, methods, etc.) It'd be cool if this was the first google result for "Object Required line 1" and it actually contained some useful information.

PS: if somebody reputable could create an object-required-line-1 tag or similar, I'll tag this with it.

Comment: I took my time looking through the page and found one:
`var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Search Services');
searchForm.initAutocomplete('http://web199-dev.hhscloud.info/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');`

Easily fixed with a .ready() equivalent.